# https setup - link shows directory listing instead of webpage

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, lampp

I am trying to enable `https` on my lampp server according to this article

http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-setup-http-protocol-with-ssl-on-lamp-environment/

but when I try to access 'https://mywebsite.com' it shows me the directory listing of htdocs folder.

virtual host confit

```
<Virtualhost mysite.com:443>
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfolder/
    ServerName mysite.com:443
    ErrorLog /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
    TransferLog /opt/lampp/logs/access_log
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/mysite.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/mysite.com.key
    <filesmatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </filesmatch>
    <directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myfolder">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog /opt/lampp/logs/ssl_request_log \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</Virtualhost>
```

THanks

Comment: How does your ssl virtual host look like?

Comment: @rekire I edited, did you mean this ?

Comment: Yes I did. But right now I see no problem.

Comment: So do I, that's why I posted a question :) Thanks @rekire

Comment: no I don't, in `opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` file only this one

Comment: of course I did, but good question !